# $2 \times 2$ Orthogonal Matrices and their determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers. Show that there exists a unique $2 \times 2$
real symmetric matrix $A$ with $\mathrm{trace}(A) = a$ and $\det(A) = b$ if and only if $a^2=4b$.

Comment: Hmm... Does $a^2 - 4b = 0$ remind you of anything? Perhaps if you swap around the names of the two letters? That's where I would look first if I were trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-sophisticated approach.

A $2 \times 2$ non-symmetric real matrix is of the form

$$\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    p & q  \\
    q & s \\
        \end{matrix}\
\right)
$$
with $p,q,s \in \mathbb R$.

Its determinant is $ps-q^2=b,$ and its trace is $p+s=a$.

$q$ must be $0$, or else $-q$ would be another solution and it would not be unique.

We therefore have two equations in two unknowns:  $ps=b$ and $p+s=a.$

Solving these involves a quadratic equation with discriminant $a^2-4b,$

so there is a unique solution iff $a^2=4b.$